# How can I write to a child process stdin obtained with fork() in python?

Tags: python, fork

Well, I need to write to stdin of a child process obtained with fork(). I also need to keep the file descriptor(?) of stdin to the parent process for repeating writes to child. I use **`os.pipe()`** to get the descriptors, so please keep it this way.

```
pid = fork()
if pid == 0:
    os.write(sys.stdin.fileno(), "sample") # <-- isn't this the child's stdin?
    os.execv(..)
    .
    .
```

the child process is a bash script, sth like:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/mplayer -slave "$1" <&0
```

Apparently, I want to control mplayer with python using its `slave` mode that receives commands from its stdin

fork() is essential because of the structure of the program, so please no alternatives using `communicate`, etc

Comment: I don't believe that "fork() is essential because of the structure of the program". There might be some obscure cases where that's true (which don't involve "because I want to do something illegal that only works 90% of the time between `fork` and `exec` and just cross my fingers every time I run it"), but I don't think someone who'd ask this question would have such a case…

Comment: Sorry that we don't know as much as you do.

Comment: Nobody knows everything about everything, but if you're going to get offended when people notice your lack of knowledge, instead of trying to learn from it, you're going to find it very hard to get ahead in anything.

Comment: It is impossible for me to be offended by my lack of knowledge since I ask!
My comment has to do with your first comment where it seems that you need to point out the lack of someone’s knowledge, while you doubt with irony the question and its parameters. I doubt if you’ve ever got ahead in anything, after all.

Comment: You're demanding that people answer your question the hard way instead of the easy way--and doing so in pretty blunt terms. If you want to do that, you have a responsibility to make it clear that you understand what you're talking about, or most people are likely to just ignore you. You can complain about me calling you on that attitude, but notice that I'm the only one who answered your question for you; what do you think that says about how others took your demands?

Comment: **General** questions have general and multiple answers. **Specific** questions always have limited answers (like this one). That's why you are the only one that gave an answer and not my attitude. "I am demanding"? Where did this come from? Anyway, as you can see I use the word **please** in every single "demand" (parameter actually).  I had a specific situation which had to be solved. Asking the general version wouldn't have solved my issue and those questions have already been answered. I do undersand what I'm talking about: see my comment on your answer.

Answer (score 6):

What you're trying to do is impossible, because it doesn't make sense. The child has the same stdin as the parent, not a new one that you can write to. POSIX guarantees that after [`fork`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html):

> The child process shall have its own copy of the parent's file descriptors. Each of the child's file descriptors shall refer to the same open file description with the corresponding file descriptor of the parent.

---

Meanwhile, you're trying to write to the child's stdin from within the child. That makes even less sense. What do you expect writing to your own stdin to do?

---

Of course the child can write to its own stdout, which will be the same as the parent's stdout. But I suspect that's not what you want. What you want is for the parent to write to the child's stdin.

If so, you have to create a pipe before forking, then replace the child's stdin with the read side of that pipe (usually by using `dup2`), then write to the write side of that pipe. The [CPython `subprocess` implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Modules/_posixsubprocess.c#l370) is great example code for how to do that without relying on higher-level functions (even though it's in C, rather than in Python).

Something like this:

```
pr, pw = pipe()
pid = fork()
if pid == 0:
    os.close(pw)
    sys.stdin.close()
    os.dup2(pr, 0)
    os.execv(...)
else:
    os.close(pr)
    os.write(pw, "sample")
```

Comment: ... the line you were based to conclude that I don't know what I'm talking about, has a comment! Its comment is part of the question. Ok, I've put the `os.write` there - mistake - but it is not part of actual program: Instead of posting tenths of lines of code, I use to "transform" the question into a more compact form making it more readable and easy for someone to get into, like you that you did understand what I'm trying to accomplish - I don't think that you've just guessed. The question **is** clear. Your code works! Thanks.